# Add Misc Mod to Diplomacy PCGen

Tags: skills, tools, pcgen

So I've just started using PCGen... And while I mostly love the app, there seems to be a small oversight. There is no simple way of adding a Misc Mod to a skill.

For example, I got +6 diplomacy bonus permanently from a Deck of Many Things. I am trying to add that bonus, and there is no simple way of doing it. Hours of googling has only turned up LST file creation which seems extremely over the top to add a simple bonus. I gave it a try regardless, and when I went to load the source, it didn't change anything on Diplomacy.

**Is there another way to add a Misc Modifier?**

Comment: The question would be improved by tagging it with the game system involved.

Comment: Are you playing Dungeons and Dragons?  If so, which edition?  Are you playing Pathfinder?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using 6.06.01+ on the feats and abilities tab look for GM Awards you can add misc modifiers there.